Flutter build number on android always increased by 2000 for no apparent reason
I have the most strange behaviour in Flutter, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it happens. It is not a critical bug in any way, I am just so annoyed that I can't find the reason for it!
I have a Flutter-app, that is built for iOS and Android. The dependency Package Info Plus is used to retrieve the app version and build number using this simple widget:
class AppVersionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppVersionWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _getAppVersion(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
            ? Text(
                'v${snapshot.data}',
                style: context.textTheme.bodySmall!.apply(
                  color: context.customColorScheme?.whiteFixed,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )
            : const SizedBox.shrink(),
      );

  Future<String> _getAppVersion() async {
    final packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

    final appVersion = packageInfo.version;
    final buildVersion = packageInfo.buildNumber;

    return '$appVersion ($buildVersion)';
  }
}

On iOS, this works perfectly, if the app version is 1.0.0 and the build number is 123, it will output 1.0.0 (123). On android however, it outputs 1.0.0 (2123). I have tried different build numbers, and realised that on android, the number 2000 is always added to the build number. If I change build number to 12345, it will output 14345. Why???
I have done some debugging, in build.gradle I added the following:
println "Debug Output: Version Code = ${flutterVersionCode}"
println "Debug Output: Version Name = ${flutterVersionName}"

And during the Android build-process, it correctly outputs:
Debug Output: Version Code = 123
Debug Output: Version Name = 1.0.0

No one else seems to have this issue when I search for it, so I don't really know what else to try or what the reason might be?!
UPDATE
As suggested by kpwn-apps, I have now also tried to use native code to retrieve the build number, and it still doesn't work as expected, but it gave me some more information that might be a clue to the root cause?!
Outputting the value from the kotlin-code ${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE} results in a number that is incremented by 4000 instead of 2000. I output both numbers in the UI of my app, and regardless of the build number, they are always incremented in the same way.
I also discovered that the behaviour is different depending on how the app is built. I normally build the test-version of the android-app with the --split-per-abi-flag, so all issues above are tested on the arm64-v8a version of the apk. If I remove this flag, and build the bigger appbundle, the build number displays the correct number for both the flutter and native variants.
So it seems to be related to --split-per-abi, but I still don't understand why, or what I can do about it if I want to keep using that flag? I also don't understand why the build number is incremented differently depending on how I retrieve the number?
The following:
> flutter build apk --split-per-abi --build-number=1                 

Debug Output: Version Code = 1
Debug Output: Version Name = 4.0.0
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           36.5s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (25.2MB).
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (26.9MB).
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-x86_64-release.apk (28.2MB).

> adb install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk

Results in:

While this:
> flutter build apk --build-number=1                 

Debug Output: Version Code = 1
Debug Output: Version Name = 4.0.0
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           29.7s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (69.4MB).

> adb install build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk          

Results in this:

Which is correct, but the APK gets unnecessarily big for testing purposes.

i use " flutter build apk --release -v --split-per-abi", get the same question.  packageInfo.buildNumber always increase 2000

it not an issue in the plugin, but Flutter tools.
see this anser in fluttercommunity/plus_plugins.
Wrong build number on android
Solution:
Edit flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle
Or   flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
private static final Map ABI_VERSION = [
    (ARCH_ARM32)        : 0,
    (ARCH_ARM64)        : 0,
    (ARCH_X86)          : 0,
    (ARCH_X86_64)       : 0,
]


That indeed seems to be the answer to why this happens, thanks! We have however stopped using --split-per-abi just because of this issue.

Looks like a bug of the package. Try implementing it on the Android part.
Create method channel:
val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,CHANNEL)

and set call handler
 channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            if (call.method == "appversion") {
                val versionString = "${BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME} - ${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE}"
                result.success(versionString)
            }
        }

now in your dart part create a class like
class AppInfo {

  final MethodChannel methodChannel = const MethodChannel("channel");

  Future<String> getAppVersion() async {
    final ver = await methodChannel.invokeMethod("appversion");
    return ver;
  }
}

Now you can get the version by
await AppInfo().getAppVersion();


Thanks! It was a good idea, but the issue partly remains, see my updated question.
